# An angle in triangles inside a circumference

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Excuse me, I was doing this problem, when a friend told me that the angle 120° and 70° were talking about the angle to the center of the circle. I don't know how to solve this (finding X), since the angles are not central. Any help, or name of theorems that could help, I would be very grateful. Thank you!

(I added the blue lines to the center to help me visualize the angles 70° and 120°)

[image]

Comment: You need the [Inscribed Angle Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inscribed_angle).

Comment: Thank you very much. Excuse me, but from where? I cannot find the angle that starts it to find the Inscribed Angle

Comment: I thought that the angle 120° was saying that was the angle inbetween BD (y), which would make the angle next to E the Alternate Segment; but if 120° is actually to the center, then I am quite lost.

Comment: Take chord $BC$ for example. It will subtend an angle of $35^0$ at point $D$, half of what it subtends at the center. It will also subtend the same angle at any points on the circle.

Comment: Ooh, thank you so much, @MathLover I see! Okay, then, I will work with that :) Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you very much, @player3236. I think I have now been able to solve it. Thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: Thank you very much, @MathLover . I think I have now been able to solve it. Thanks a lot!! :) And I have learnt something new. Thanks!!